# ApplyBindings to an array using Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an AJAX request that returns an array of objects (Results). In the success callback function, the binding is applied using:

```
success: function(data) {
                ko.applyBindings(new ResultsViewModel(data), target);
         }
```

Where `target` is the target DOM element, and `ResultsViewModel` is created similar to:

```
function ResultsViewModel(model) {
    var self = this;
    self.text = ko.observable(model.text);
    self.id = model.id;
    self.Descriptions = ko.observableArray(model.descriptions);
}
```

In my HTML, the data is bound to the elements using:

```html
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'results-template', foreach: $data}">
```

Then a template class that binds the individual properties of the view model.

My question is: how can I bind the array of data that is returned by my AJAX call (multiple result objects) using the viewmodel with a mixture of observable and static properties to the DOM?

The foreach loop I am using should create a template and bind each object in the returned array to a separate div, but it looks as though it is attempting to bind the root object in the returned array, which is null (unnamed array).

Comment: It would help if you show us what your `model` is like, and a few more bits of your view (specifically: the template).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're misusing the `$data` "special context property" (as the [knockout.js docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_1_referring_to_each_array_entry_using_data) calls it). Quoting:

> But what if you want to refer to the array entry itself (not just one of its properties)? In that case, you can use the special context property $data. Within a foreach block, it means “the current item”.

You're not really using a `foreach` binding, though: it's a template binding. In the docs for the [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), they never use the `foreach: $data` syntax, it's always `foreach: somePropOnTheViewModel`.

Have you tried doing that instead? I can't be certain if this will do what you want without seeing the rest of the HTML for the binding you're applying it to, but I think this would work for your template code:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'results-template', foreach: Descriptions}">
```

Answer (score 1):

We can (somewhat) see where you're going with this. Your question is not 100% clear, so it's impossible to give a definitive answer (I suggest going through [the KnockoutJS tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) because you seem to have a few basic KO concepts mixed up). Nonetheless, here's one direction you could take.

As mentioned in the other answer, you use the `template` binding, but you don't indicate *why* you'd need that, as the `foreach` binding should suffice. The data for that template would be the `Descriptions` observable array, not `$data`. You're entire View (when keeping the use of the `template` binding) should look like something like this:

### Option 1

```html
<script type="text/html" id="results-template">
    <span data-bind="text: desc"></span><br />
</script>

<h4 data-bind="text: text"></h4>
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'results-template', foreach: Descriptions}">
</div>
```

This is assuming your `Descriptions` are complex objects that look like this:

```
[{ id: 12, desc: "Feels good" }, ... ]
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MaPb/) for a demo.

### Option 2

If your descriptions are just flat strings then your View's template needs to change and it *does* use the `$data` variable:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="results-template">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span><br />
</script>
```

This is assuming your data looks like this:

```
["Feels good", ... ]
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVdVp/) for a demo.

---

As a footnote, I noticed:

- `self.id` is no observable, is that intentional?
- you use a specific `target` when applying bindings, but from your question I see no reason why you'd need that?

In my example fiddle I've changed those two things.